# How do I make the weights symmetrical?

Tags: mesh, bones, weight-painting, mirror, vertex-weights

Good day all. I hope you are well.

So today I was messing about on this random character. Made with mirror mode then applied it once done. Made the armature, used the symmetrize option on the legs only.

Tried to sign automatic weights. All is on the left side but the right...? Completely not!

Is there a way how I can mirror the weights from the left over to the right?

Thank you for your time.[image]

Comment: apply mirror to the mesh before parenting amature,

Comment: I think my mirror mode you mean a mirror modifier. Not sure what’s going on here…